# Numpy.distutils path to Fortran modules from compiled library

Tags: python, fortran, ffi, distutils

I am creating a Python wrapper around a C and Fortran library. I would like the code from this C/Fortran library to be compiled by pip, so the user isn't required to install the library themselves before running pip. I currently achieve this using Numpy Distutils, with a setup.py similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration('name', parent_package, top_path)
    f90_src = [<list of .f90 files>]
    c_src = [<list of .c files>]
    src = c_src + f90_src
    config.add_library('libname', sources=src,
                       extra_f90_compile_args=['-pthread', '-fno-underscoring'])
    config.add_extension(name='wrapper_name', sources=['wrapper_name.f90'],
                         extra_f90_compile_args=['-pthread'], libraries=['libname'],
                         module_dirs=['build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/'])

    return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(configuration=configuration)
```

The library contains Fortran modules, so when compiling my wrapper that calls the library (and `use`s its modules), I need to tell the compiler where to find the modules. That is the `module_dirs` option. The problem is that I had to hard-code this. Is there a portable and robust way to find the path to this directory instead?

Note that I have to compile the code that I am wrapping using `add_library` rather than putting it in the `sources` of `add_extension` as if I do the latter `f2py` will try to wrap all of the interfaces in that code, but it uses some features of Fortran that `f2py` does not support and so compilation fails.

One workaround may be to change the code to use interfaces rather than modules, but the code that I am wrapping is large and it is not feasible to make any such large modifications to it.

The `config.get_build_temp_dir()` function sounds promising, but raises an error if called in the place where it is needed (saying it has not yet been initialized).

Comment: Not a solution to your specific question, however, Why not compile and link your C/Fortran codes and release the shared files instead of giving the raw C/Fortran codes to the users to compile it by themselves? A large fraction of the available architecture in the market is amd64 nowadays. So if you build your library for this architecture, you have already supported a big chunk of the users' community.

Comment: Thank you, that is a possibility. It's not as elegant as I was hoping for, might be problematic for users with other operating systems, and it's a pity to have to go that route when I seem to be so close to the ideal solution with my current approach (I just need to avoid that hardcoded path), but perhaps it is the best that is possible.